# Prove that if $F$ is a linear functional then $F(0) = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

Prove that if $F$ is a linear functional then $F(0) = 0\, $(assume the function u = 0 is in the domain of $F$).

My attempt...

*Proof*
Let $v,w$ be arbitrary functions in the domain of $F$, then
$$F(0) = F(0\cdot v + 0\cdot w) = 0\cdot F(v) + 0\cdot F(w) = 0$$

Is this wrong/too simple?

Comment: If anything it is too complicated. $F(0) = F(0v) = 0F(v) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{ }$
Yes, correct. Also $F(0)=F(0)+F(0) \implies F(0)=0.$
$\text{ }$

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. More simple: let $u$ be in the domain of $F$.

$$F(0) = F(0\cdot u) = 0\cdot F(u) = 0$$

And by the way you can see that $u=0$ *must* be in the domain of $F$ (i.e. no need to assume this) because it is linear.

---

@Umberto P. sorry, saw your comment too late.